# backup of postgresql database from my application

Tags: c#, postgresql, backup

I've got application which contains a database based on Postgresql. I wannna get a backup of this database using my application. for ex. I wanna click an option in program menu and wanna get file with database backup. I got all administratior rights for this database. Application is wrtitten in .net 4.0 (C#), windows forms.

How could I solve my problem?

---

i' ve tried it but it's not working:

```
 string zapytanie = @"pg_dump WFR > C:\kopia";
                string pol = Ustawienia.ConnectionString;
                NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(pol);
                conn.Open();
                NpgsqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
                comm.CommandText = zapytanie;

                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
```

errors:

ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "pg_dump"

stacktrace:

```
w Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses_Ver_3>d__a.MoveNext()
   w Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject()
   w Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRowDescription()
   w Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.NextResult()
   w Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 dataEnumeration, CommandBehavior behavior, NpgsqlCommand command, NotificationThreadBlock threadBlock, Boolean synchOnReadError)
   w Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(CommandBehavior cb)
   w Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   w Faktury_i_Rachunki_2.Forms.FrmKopiaBezp.BtUtworzKopie_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) w D:\nwfr3\Faktury i Rachunki 2.0\Forms\FrmKopiaBezp.cs:wiersz 38
```

Comment: Have you tried to read the postgre manual? first hit in Google when searching for `postgresql backup command`. Explain why if those commands are not enough for you

Comment: i' ve tried it but it's not working:

string zapytanie = @"pg_dump WFR > C:\kopia";
            string pol = Ustawienia.ConnectionString;
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(pol);
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText = zapytanie;
            
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

Comment: add that to your question (formatted) and not as a comment. also include any error messages

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can include a copy of `pg_dump.exe` binary for Ms Windows (and required dlls) with your application. Then invoke it with proper parameters from a GUI.

(you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out what libraries are required by `pg_dump.exe`)

Answer (score 1):

`pg_dump` is a tool and not a SQL command. You need to execute it using `Process.Start`.

pg_dump outputs a SQL script. So you need some way to capture the SQL script form standard out. It can be achieved in the following way: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/edwinlima/SystemDiagnosticProcess12052005035444AM/SystemDiagnosticProcess.aspx

Comment: Thank you for help. I'll check it and when I get solution, I'll paste here. Have a nice day!